# MVC Dropdownlist with multiple doesn't bind with server values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have the following element

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedEmployees, Model.Employees, new { @class = "form-control select2", multiple = "1" })
</div>
```

When I select the items and I do a Postback the values are found "SelectedEmployees" which is a List, but if I put default values in the List it will not bind back to the dropdown list when I open the page.
I am using the select2 bootstrap control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the DropDownList

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2">Linked Employees</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedEmployees, Model.Employees, new { @class = "form-control select2", multiple = "1" })
     </div>
</div>
```

The html generate stays the same client side but the binding works now